# RateLimit issue with selenium scripts test run

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using http://mailinator.com/ in my automation scripts for all email related tests. It works well for me but after having certain amount of script execution it does not work and It routes user to a page called to "ratelimit.jsp".

It does not work for couple of days and then It again start working. Can anybody help me here to deal with ratelimit with email providers?

Comment: please provide your script to check this

Answer (score 1):

Mailinator has rate-limits on how many email's you can send.

> Can anybody help me to deal with ratelimit with email providers?

You have a couple options that I can think of.

1. Since Mailinator is specifically for QA testing, you could upgrade your plan.  See their [pricing plans...](http://mailinator.com/featurematrix.jsp)
2. Switch to a different provider.  There are several options, even Gmail.  Or you could use your own custom mail server.